# Issue when getting data from text field in dynamic cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have created a dynamic table, but I'm facing an issue when I try to access the content of a text field in the first cell. The textfield I get is always empty, even though I enter some text in it before calling the action.

Here is my code. Could you help me to find what's wrong in it ?

CustomNameCell.h

```
@interface CustomNameCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@end
```

CustomViewController.h

```
@interface CustomViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    - (IBAction)search:(id)sender;
@end
```

CustomViewController.m :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"nameCell";
        CustomNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[CustomNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    ...
```

and the action when clicking a button, where I try to get the content of the textfield :

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"nameCell";
CustomNameCell *nameCell = [_tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

here nameCell.nameTextField.text is always equal to @""
```

Why is my text field always empty ?

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: you shouldn't call the _tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier in the search method how do you store the data you are displaying in your table?

Comment: My tableview contains dynamic but also "static" cells. I call this method to get a specific cell, the first one, which contains a search text field. When clicking a button, the search text field is used to populate date in the other cells on the table.

Comment: This is NOT the way you should do this. Can you actually specify what do you need ?

Comment: I can't get a specific cell using the cellIdentifier ? I just want to know the content of nameTextField.text in the first cell...

Comment: @Nanego when u call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier this is just a mechanism to reuse a cell you have created when building your tableView

Comment: ok, I thought I could use this mechanism to read the data typed in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `[_tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`within your - `(IBAction)search:(id)sender` as it is a mechanism to reuse a cell during the creation of your tableView. Instead of creating new cell when you are scrolling your tableview you are reusing some cells you have previously created.

**Bottom line:** use instead the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to access a cell at a specific row in your section and if you want the first cell of the first section it would be:

```
CustomNameCell * cell = (CustomNameCell *)[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had hope to use identifier instead of indexes but it works well with the index. Moreover, this helped me to resolved other issues. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you need a cell you should get it like this:

```
CustomNameCell * cell = (CustomNameCell *)[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString * textInField = cell.nameTextField.text;
```

If you tell me what logic do you need I'll expand my question. For now - you can use this method.

Content of the first cell will be:

```
CustomNameCell * cell = (CustomNameCell *)[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
NSString * textInField = cell.nameTextField.text;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had hope to use identifier instead of indexes but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I just do in this Way.  I dont know it is the current way to do that.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return cellContentArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    UITextField *firsttext=[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UITextField *second=[cell viewWithTag:102];
    [second setTag:(indexPath.row)+1000];
    [firsttext setTag:(indexPath.row)+100];
    return cell;
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    for (int i=0; i<cellContentArray.count; i++) {
        UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[baseTableveiew cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        UITextField *tempTextField=[cell viewWithTag:i+100];
        UITextField *secondTextField=[cell  viewWithTag:i+1000];
        NSString * textInField = tempTextField.text;
        NSLog(@"tempTExtTiedl tag %ld data %@",(long)tempTextField.tag, textInField);
        NSLog(@"second tag %ld data %@",(long)secondTextField.tag, secondTextField.text);
    }

}
```